# OSGi - ServiceTracker - ServiceTrackerCustomizer

Tags: osgi

The constructor of a service tracker is for example:
`ServiceTracker(BundleContext,Filter,ServiceTrackerCustomizer)`

where the ServiceTrackerCustomizer implements the following interface:

```
   public interface ServiceTrackerCustomizer {
 public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference);
 public void modifiedService(ServiceReference reference, Object service);
 public void removedService(ServiceReference reference, Object service);
```

}

I understand the customizer to be of great help if you want for example to add custom actions when the service that is being tracked is registered, etc.

But I am struggling to understand what the reference that is passed in "addingService" is, as well as how the object that is returned is defined.

Say you want to track a service which reference is REF and you want to print a message whenever the service is added. The customizer would be something like:

```
public class MyServiceTrackerCustomizer implements ServiceTrackerCustomizer {
    // Is REF the ref provided "behind the scene"?
    public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("In tracker customizer -> service added");

        // What is the object returned?
        return Object;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any clarification you may provide.
Christian

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at the default implementation of `addingService` in the ServiceTracker class?

```
    public T addingService(ServiceReference<S> reference) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T result = (T) context.getService(reference);
        return result;
    }
```

Of course you may want to return a different object to track. For example, you could wrap the actual service object in some wrapper, you could not get the service object now and just return the reference, or you could examine the reference and decide you don't care to track it by returning `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I get it. I also looked into the implementation code of ServiceTracker and was expecting to see something like the following in the addingService (in pseudo code): "if the ServiceCustomizer is not null when constructing the Tracker, the use serviceCustomizer.addingService else context.getService(reference)" but there is none of that ... I'm sure I'm missing something here ...

Comment: If the customizer argument to the ServiceTracker constructor is null, it uses itself as the customizer since it also implements ServiceTrackerCustomizer and it thus the default implementation of ServiceTrackerCustomizer.

Answer (score 2):

The ServiceTracker allows you to create and store any object you like in the addingService method and then reuse this object in modifiedService and removedService.

The default behaviour is to get the service object in addingService and unget it in removedService. So while you can do what you like you should make sure that if you get the service object you should also unget it later.

With the default behaviour you can use the service tracker getService() method to work with the currently found service but this means your code depends on the OSGi APIs which is not ideal.

So one other use case is to create your pojo and inject it with the service in addingService. You can then store your pojo by returning it. Then in modifiedService and removedService you can work with your pojo. For example you can call a destroy method on it on remove.

One advanced use case it to create and store another ServiceTracker. So with the outer ServiceTracker you could track ServiceA and with the inner one ServiceB. Inside the inner one you could then create your pojo and inject it with both services. So this allows you to solve the case where your pojo should only be active when both services are available. For an example see [TransactionManagerTracker](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/blob/master/pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/jdbc/pool/dbcp2/impl/TransactionManagerTracker.java). It tracks a TransactionManager service. If it is found it creates another tracker that then tracks a DataSourceFactory service. If both are available then the pojo PooledDataSourceFactory is created with both. If one of the services goes away then it is destroyed again.

Neil wrote an excellent article that also covers some additionaal cases. See [When ServiceTracker Trumps Declarative Services](http://njbartlett.name/2010/08/05/when-servicetrackers-trump-ds.html). In fact this article made me realize that I could cover my above case with ServiceTracker.

Comment: looks like both of your links are dead. Any chance you can fix them if those resources are still out there somewhere?